# WiX Auto-generated Component Guid vs Predefined Guids

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I've read about auto-generated GUID against predefined one. E.g. I've read, that when using Language transforms (for multilingual installer), it is better to have predefined ones. And for simple installer it is not an issue, to use either.

**INTRODUCTION:**

I have project that have multiple installers, each one for different customer, with some customisation of config files and graphics. Currently we are using simple Windows Installer Projects from Visual Studio 2010. I'm planning to move that into WiX.

**CHALLENGE:**

Because quite a lot files are shared I wonder is it good have one wxs file with defined components in it. The problem is, if that components can have predefined GUIDs, or have to have auto-generated ones. I'm planning either attach that file into multiple projects using linked item or will create wixlib. Because I don't have experience yet with wixlibs, I don't know which will suit me better.

Even if files in setups are the same, they are not installed into the same folder, and have to managed separately, so I cannot use plain shared components (e.g by using merge module). For MSI they won't be shared, I just want to share some code to avoid duplications when possible.

**QUESTION**

So, have I use auto-generated GUIDs or I can predefined ones? I'm a bit confused which one is for which solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the "shared files" are installed in separate folders, then they are not really shared, rather it is multiple copies of the same files, and it is safe to have different IDs for their Wix components.

Comment: I'm rather asking is it safe to have the same GUIDS.